# Less treasure cards in Dungeon! board game

Tags: dungeon

I was playing a game of [Dungeon!](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1339/dungeon). Sometimes when treasures are consumed by traps, there are no treasure cards but there are rooms with monsters(not yet revealed). How does that work? Does that mean there are some rooms where there are monsters but no treasure up for grabs?(That sounds a bit broken then :P )

For clarity, here are the texts from the traps:

**Slide trap**: *Gain 1 Treasure and move to any chamber on Level 4*

**Cage trap**: *Gain 1 treasure and Roll a die. 1-3: Lose 1 turn, 4-6: Lose 2 turns*

(This now goes further to my other question posted [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/retreat-in-case-of-slide-trap-in-dungeon).)

Is there a forum to post rules errata for the game?

Comment: I am not familiar with the game, but is it possible that some monsters have multiple treasures or some treasures do not get handed out?

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs: Nopes, on the other hand, a "trap" will ensure you get a treasure, and monster cards anyway get shuffled back from the discard pile.

Comment: Is your title backwards?  You're seeing too many monsters and not enough treasure, right?  Are you aware that only rooms have treasure, not chambers?

Comment: @bwarner I think I got that wrong - updated it now. The monster cards will never run out because you will always shuffle back the monster cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of treasure cards is equal to the number of rooms that exist on each level.  You only get treasure when defeating a monster or triggering a trap in a room.  Therefore, it should never be possible to run out of treasure cards.  My guess is that you were mistakenly awarding treasure in chambers, which should not be the case.

From the rules:

"Monsters in Rooms have treasure; those in Chambers do not."

Answer (score 2):

The rules of the games in the booklet supersede those on the trap cards. We also misplayed this until I deeply read the booklet, running into the same problem of running out of treasure. 
When a trap is played as a monster in a room, you get a treasure. When a trap is sprung as a monster in a chamber, you still get the effects of the trap, but not a treasure card. Here's another way to think about it. The only place in the game where you get to DRAW a treasure card is inside a room. If you get treasure in a chamber, it should only be because it was dropped there earlier by another player who failed to defeat a monster there.