# Retreat in case of slide trap in Dungeon!

Tags: mechanics, dungeon

In a game of [Dungeon!](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1339/dungeon) there is **Slide Trap** in Level 3 which says:

*Gain 1 Treasure and move to any chamber on Level 4*

What happens when I encounter a monster in the level 4 chamber, attack it insufficiently, the monster hits back, and I have to retreat a step? Where do I retreat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the idea of the retreat system is to prevent you from passing a chamber by not killing a monster, we always play that you **must** go back the way you came. In case a trap brought you to a chamber you probably had no intention to pass that chamber anyway, since you did not mean to go to that chamber. So passing without killing a monster is not relevant in this case. We allow the unlucky player who ended up in the trap and who didn't kill the monster in the chamber to choose the path of retreat. It's not like it's that much of an advantage since the player never really intended to enter that chamber.

I don't know whether there is any official rule on this matter but this approach seems logical to me.

Answer (score 1):

Now I do not know of an official ruling, but in this instance my group has always practiced that **retreat** is not the same as **return**.

That is to say the rules are telling you, that you are to no longer occupy the same chamber/room as the monster, not that you must go back the way you came.

I have not played *Dungeon!* but I have played *New Dungeon* which was a precursor to that game.

We always played that **retreat** simply means you move out of the chamber/room you are in, in whatever direction you fancy.

To pretend for a moment: While you are fighting a monster you are moving all around. Who is to say you are on the same side of the room as you started and near the same door you entered through?

Comment: If you may not "go back the way you came", then you can always cross a chamber by attacking the monster, but retreating in a separate direction - which is why retreating should mean go back the way you came, no?

Comment: Well retreating is not always going back the way you came. From the first definition google gives us: **withdraw from enemy forces as a result of their superior power or after a defeat.** So even if you are not going the same way you entered, you are still retreating. We actually play that way. If you lose in a chamber, you go out whatever way you want. Even if that means you are 'crossing' the chamber.

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered this as well. I remember reading that you are supposed to retreat the way you came in. This is probably to prevent players from "retreating" their way through a chamber past a particularly nasty monster to get to the treasure rooms beyond. In the case of a forced entry into a chamber due to a trap sending you there, it doesn't make a lot of sense to retreat back up the slide that dumped you there. We play that if you are forced to retreat because you entered a chamber due to trap, you retreat randomly down one of the passages into the chamber, chosen by die roll.