# Do you get treasure if you don't kill the Dungeon! Monster?

Tags: dungeon

I've been reading [the *Dungeon!* WOTC rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20170405010950/http://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/Dungeon%21_Rulebook.pdf), and have a peculiar question: the rules state

> If you encountered the Monster in a room, you draw 1 Treasure card from the face-down pile of cards corresponding to the Level the Monster was on. You also collect any other Treasures that were dropped there by Heroes.
>
> If you encountered the Monster in a chamber, you do not draw a random Treasure card, but you do collect any Treasures that were dropped there by Heroes.

However, the definition of "encounter" seems to simply be "there is a monster":

> After your Hero has finished moving, he or she encounters that space. If your Hero is in a corridor space, a cleared room (with 1 Cleared token) or a cleared chamber (with 3 Cleared tokens), no Monsters are there. Your turn is over. Otherwise, follow the steps below.

Finally, not killing Monsters has the following outcomes:

> - **Killed**! Drop all your Treasure cards. Choose a new Hero (or the same one if no other Hero is available) and place it on the Great Hall.
> - **Seriously Wounded**: Randomly drop half your 11 Treasure cards (round up) and place your Hero on
>   the Great Hall.
> - **Wounded**: Drop 1 random Treasure card and move your Hero back 1 space in the direction he or she came. Take 1 Lose a Turn token.
> - **Stunned**: Drop 1 random Treasure card.
> - **Miss**! No effect.

From my reading, despite the potential negative effects, it seems like each of these is still an encounter, meaning that a Hero gains treasure as long as the Monster was in a room, full-stop.

Is my logical conclusion correct? Does a Hero draw a Treasure card if there is a Monster in a room, no matter what happens in combat?

---

As a GM for D&D, and a board-game enthusiast, this seems... wrong? The game would move far too quickly if you got treasure just from seeing monsters, and makes no fictional sense either.

I did find [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/13672/27037) which suggests that you only get treasure if you defeat the Monster.

Are the rules just missing a statement at the end of each result of not killing a Monster to the effect of "Your turn is now over. Skip the Looting phase." ? Alternatively, could it mean "If you defeated the Monster in a room, you draw 1 Treasure card [...]" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules booklet that comes with the box-game is clearer (and, clearly, updated from the PDF linked by WOTC): it states quite clearly the results of not killing a Monster, and clarifies that you only win treasure by defeating Monsters.